# Cannot disable VSCode to remove ending whitespace on save?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, prettier

I have realized a behaviour of VSCode that causing conflict on committing files in an Angular project. When saving a file (*.ts), VSCode removes the ending whitespaces automatically and I have not managed to disable it by using lots of settings changes etc. as shown below. So, how can I disable it? And I do not want to open format on save feature as well.

***settings.json:***

```
"[markdown]": {
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false
}

"editor.trimAutoWhitespace": false,
```

or using UI: File → Preference → Settings → Search and uncheck Trim Trailing Whitespace option.

But it still the same behaviour. ANy idea to fix it? I have installed Prettier also.

```
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true
```

Comment: Trailing whitespace can also be removed by extensions, such as code formatters or .editorconfig. Perhaps you can verify if it also happens in safe mode (with no extensions loaded).

Comment: Thansk amigo. How can I open it easily in safe mode?

Comment: Define easily ;-) You can type `code --disable-extensions` in a console.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see that the problem is **EditorConfig for VSCode**. So, maybe I can have a look at its settings and disable the property that cause this problem. Because I want to use this extension.

Comment: BTW, Visual Studio Code 1.52.0 has just added a feature to ease this kind of diagnose: [Extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52#_troubleshooting-extension-bisect).

Comment: Very good amigo ;)

Answer (score 0):

After disabling and deselecting as many extensions & settings as concerned the issue of visual studio code removing my spaces, but with no positive results, I found out that the issue was with this one simple move, `Auto Save` deselecting that is what worked for me. (Files -> Auto Save)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this annoying behavior by removing the latest installed extensions in VS code.